# Does Perl have a timeout, if so, how to disable it?

Tags: perl, timeout

Is there any syntax or function to run a Perl script for infinite time (no time limit)?

PHP has [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) so what is the equivalent in Perl?

Comment: You can use an infinte while loop! Once a condition is met, break from the loop.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you actually run into a real time limit that caused a Perl script of yours to time out?

Comment: i'm using while loop here.

Comment: Do you actually want your script to continue running without any user interruption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl does not impose a time limit on the execution time of scripts. As such, there's no means to disable any such time limit.